# Retrieve data from AWS S3 by selecting elements from Glue Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm trying to figure out, is it possible to have someone select a list of Tables/Elements from AWS Glue Catalog (which has all the metadata of the data stored in AWS S3 lets say), and upon selection, have these Tables/Data Elements automatically retrieved into a AWS S3 bucket or Redshift Table (could be spectrum) or RDS table.

Comment: To clarify, is the goal to read data from files in an S3 bucket, and insert or update that data in a RedShift or RDS table? What do you mean by "upon selection". If you can update your question about a specific use case, with more detail, I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Sure. Intent being AWS Glue Catalog will serve as a selection for Tables/columns etc. When a user selects these, have an API call to retrieve these from AWS S3 bucket to a new bucket. Where the user can either download these files and run reports off it.